# Предикатив в качестве подлежащего

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

```
1. Охота мне была пойти по бабам. 
2. Охота мне было пойти по бабам.
```

Проведите синтаксический разбор предложения (1) с точки зрения классического, официального синтаксиса. Отличается ли он от (2) ? Является ли **охота** существительным в (1), в (2)?

Comment: в первом: охота - подлежащее, мне дополнение, была - сказуемое, пойти по бабам - дополнение. Во втором: было - частица?

Comment: Буратино Недержание очередное, очередное недержание.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Охота мне былА** пойти по бабам.*

Правильно: ***Охота у меня** была пойти по бабам.*

Встречается: ***Охота мне** была пойти по бабам.*

Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

**ОХОТА** I ж. разг. Желание, стремление, склонность к чему-либо.

**Двусоставное**, пред. основа: ***охота была,*** инфинитив в роли несогласованного определения, ***у меня (мне)*** — дополнение.

2. ***Охота мне былО** пойти по бабам.*

**ОХОТА** IV предик. разг.-сниж. О наличии желания делать что-либо; хочется.

**Односоставное, безличное,** предикативная основа: ***охота было*** + примыкающий инфинитив в роли **дополнения** (изъяснит. значение, что сделать?); ***было*** — связка, обозначает прошедшее время.

**Примечание**

В старых текстах наблюдается колебание: ***была/было, мне/у меня***.

Но сейчас желательно различать значения существительного и предикатива.

**[Цитаты из русской классики](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0)**

Comment: Ну если уж вы даете как норму "у меня была" в противовес "мне была", то нужно обязательно, как минимум привести какой-то источник, где бы осмеливались так лихо нормировать РЯ. А мы бы тогда попинали автора. Но логика в такой норме есть (как вы уже сказали не смешиваем предикатив с существительным)

Comment: Хотите Кузнецова попинать? В словаре у него обозначены сущ. и предикатив. Охота тебе работать в таких условиях?  Это что? У него существительное. Тогда получится: Охота была тебе работать в таких условиях?   Или было?

Comment: Вот предложение из классической литературы с подлежащим.: Если бы у меня была охота заказать себе кольцо, то я выбрал бы такую надпись: «Ничто не проходит» (Аксаков).

Comment: Где написано что "у меня была ..." предпочтительнее чем "мне была ...", вы сам эту норму придумали? Или где-то увидели.

Comment: Нет, не видела.  И не норма это,  а обычная логика и грамматика. Если хотите использовать существительное, то пишите: Просто была у меня тогда охота  пойти, вот и пошел.   Если хотите использовать предикатив, то пишите:  Просто охота мне было  тогда пойти, вот и пошел.

Comment: Логика есть, это правда, но грамматика как раз позволяет несколько вариантов. Смотрите словарь Ушакова https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/917758 "мне была охота погулять" и он там говорит про СКАЗУЕМОЕ а не подлежащее. Но я придерживаюсь все же что это подлежащее

Comment: Да, я вижу, но у него нет другого предикатива, и тогда, наверное, так было правильно. А в современной грамматике:  было охота, было жаль и т.д. Мне думается, что для сказуемого сейчас нет вариантов.  В то же время вариант с подлежащим грамматически возможен, но с дополнением "у меня".

Comment: Тогда было правильно и сейчас правильно. Немного философии. Если что-то звучит, то это правильно, если не звучит - не правильно. Если у кого-то звучит, у кого-то нет, то либо кто-то туповат, либо так называемый "местный говор" (а чаще и то и то). В любом случае, у кого не звучит - себя обделил, у кого звучит - обогатил.

Comment: С философией согласна полностью. Даже конструкторы говорят: некрасивый самолет не полетит. Я допускаю варианты с подлежащим и сказуемым, они у меня звучат.  У Ушакова?  Там грамматика сомнительная, а звучание привычное.  "Мне"  в начале предложения никому не мешает, дальше согласование (была охота) нормальное, вот и звучит.  А вот грамматика под вопросом, она нормативной не выглядит.  Поэтому в современных словарях этого варианта со сказуемым нет.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, не знаю. Из всех предложенных вариантов чувствую структуру безличного предложения. Охота была - сказуемое (хотелось), мне - дополнение(кому?), пойти - несогласованное определение (какая охота?), по бабам - обстоятельство (куда?)

Comment: Неправда, неправда. Допустим 1 безличное как и 2. Но неужели для вас не чувствуется совершенно РАЗНАЯ структура в 1 и 2. По чувству она РАЗЛИЧНА в любом случае. По факту она тоже различна. Сравните: Мне была большая охота пойти по бабам. (та же структура) и  Мне было большая охота ??? // облом